# C26451 Arithmetic overflow accessing items in a CStringArray

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019

Got this code:

```
CString CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateDateFormatString(COleDateTime& rDate, CString strDateFormatString)
{
    CString     strDayNumber, strNewDateFormatString = strDateFormatString;

    if (theApp.UseTranslationINI())
    {
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%B"),
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_MONTH][rDate.GetMonth() - 1]);
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%A"),
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_DAY][rDate.GetDayOfWeek() - 1]);
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%b"),
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_MONTH_SHORT][rDate.GetMonth() - 1]);
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%a"),
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_DAY_SHORT][rDate.GetDayOfWeek() - 1]);

        strDayNumber = rDate.Format(_T("%d"));
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%d"), strDayNumber);
        strDayNumber = rDate.Format(_T("%#d"));
        strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%#d"), strDayNumber);
    }

    return strNewDateFormatString;
}
```

For the four `Replace` lines of code I am getting code analysis warning:

> Warning C26451
>
> Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow (io.2).

The first value inside the `[` and `]` brackets is of type `int`, but the second is a literal value of `1`:

[image: Code]

The variable `m_aryDateTrans` is defined as:

```
CStringArray m_aryDateTrans[NUM_DATE_TRANS];
```

So I am not sure what casting I need to make here to suppress this warning.

I am compiling in 32 bit and 64 bit environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cobarray-class?view=vs-2019#operator_at) of `CStringArray` takes an `INT_PTR` argument, which is 64-bits in `x64` builds and 32-bits for `x86`. So, you should use the (rather clumsy-looking) code shown below:

```
strNewDateFormatString.Replace(_T("%B"),
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_MONTH][INT_PTR(rDate.GetMonth()) - INT_PTR(1)]);
```

*(You may be able to get away without the 2nd cast - try it and see!)*

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `INT_PTR` around the `rDate` values and that stopped the warning.